# Bind to row item in Kendo for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working on an Angular app using the Kendo grid control.  How do I bind to properties of the current element?

For example, I have a list of users.  I can list them out pretty simply with this code:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="Users" style="height: 100%">
  <kendo-grid-column title="Email" field="Email"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column title="Username" field="Username"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column title="Permissions" field="Permissions"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

However, I also want to add button columns to do things like edit and delete the user.  There are also places I'm using this that I would like to have a button column that routes to a detail page for that object.  In that case I would need the id of the object to add to the route, however I don't see a way to get the object.  I want to do something like this:

```
<kendo-grid-column>
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate>
    <button routerLink="/knprojects/{{project.id}}">View Notes</button>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

The problem is that I don't have a 'project' object because there is not an *ngFor iterating items...

Sorry if it's a simple question but this is the first time I'm using their grid and first real Angular app so trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I got it.  I actually found it in the tree view documentation, I don't see it in the grid documentation but it seems to work.  If you use 'let-project' in the template definition then 'project' is the object.  So in my example it should be:

```
<kendo-grid-column>
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-project>
    <button routerLink="/knprojects/{{project.id}}">View Notes</button>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: After using the Kendo library for Angular I've noticed you really have to read between the lines on some of their examples. +1 for figuring it out. I elaborated on a similar type question here that may help you down the line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359303/get-dataitem-from-kendo-grid-with-custom-button-in-angular/52359623#52359623